# Route all traffic over Fiber VLAN

Tags: routing, vlan

Recently, I upgraded to fiber based internet, that works okay but I want to hook that up directly to my Ubuntu box instead of the supplied router. The problem is, even though I can get a valid IP via DHCP for the network interface, nothing is routed through there. Ie, I get an IP, but all networks are unreachable.

I know I am supposed to get the IP on VLAN 300. And that works. But, the configured network doesn't.

This is the interface file;

```
auto enp5s0
iface enp1s0 inet manual

auto enp5s0.300
iface enp1s0f0.5 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
bridge_ports enp5s0.300
bridge_stp off
```

In the log I do see the dhcp server handing me an IP, but after that, I can't ping the IP of that dhcp server for instance. Nor any other ip then my own. I feel like I am missing something trivial here, but can't really put my finger on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a bridge interface, you should assign an ip address on it, not on a bridge port. In your case your settings will look like:

```
auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet manual

auto enp5s0.300
iface enp5s0.300 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports enp5s0.300
bridge_stp off
```