# Route 2 VLANs over one port

Tags: routing, vlan

Related to, but expended on an earlier question of mine at [Route all traffic over Fiber VLAN](https://serverfault.com/questions/971625/route-all-traffic-over-fiber-vlan)

The fiber internet works nicely, this is the setup;

```
Media Converter
      |
      +--- Ubuntu Server
               |
               +--- Switch --- Desktop 1
                      |        Desktop 2
                      |        NAS
                      |
                      +--- Wifi ----- Laptop 1
                      |               Laptop 2
                      |               Android 1
                      |
                      +--- Switch --- TV
                                      Steam Link
                                      Set Top Box
```

And this is the network configuration

```
# The primary network interface, Internet
auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet manual

auto enp5s0.300
iface enp5s0.300 inet manual

auto enp5s0.640
iface enp5s0.640 inet manual

auto br1
iface br1 inet dhcp
    dns-namerserver 192.168.40.12 1.1.1.1
    bridge_ports enp5s0.300
    bridge_stp off

# Lan
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.40.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

This works for internet. But the Set Top Box needs be on VLAN 640. The switches are managed, they should be able to handle that. But getting the Ubuntu server to send VLAN 640 over it's eth0 interface is proving difficult. If I simply add bridge_ports enp5s0.640 to the br1, the br1 gets the IP for VLAN640.

So I am not really sure what to do to fix this. Basically, the Ubuntu server should have internet and deliver that to the whole LAN. And then VLAN640 should be delivered to the Set Top Box only for IPTV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case your configuration should be look like:

```
# The primary network interface, Internet
auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet manual

auto enp5s0.300
iface enp5s0.300 inet manual

auto enp5s0.640
iface enp5s0.640 inet manual

# Lan
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.40.12
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0.640
iface eth0.640 inet manual

auto br1
iface br1 inet dhcp
    dns-namerserver 192.168.40.12 1.1.1.1
    bridge_ports enp5s0.300
    bridge_stp off

auto br2
iface br2 inet manual
    bridge_ports enp5s0.640 eth0.640
    bridge_stp off
```

The idea is simple - you create additional bridge to switching the frames of vlan 640 to the switch transparently. Also you should create the vlan 640 on the switch itself and configure the port on it for STB in access mode.

Also, the switch port, connected to the ubuntu host, should be configured as trunk or general (various vendors use own names of modes).

Comment: That makes so much sense. I suppose I don't even need the br1 if I only want internet but don't care about it not being VLAN 300 on the lan itself?

Comment: Yep, sure. The br1 is not required if you don't connect the lan device to the vlan 300 directly.

Comment: do the bridge, eth0.640 or enp5s0.640 need IP addresses? I am trying to route 640 to my IP STB.